# Codesign does not set correct entitlements

Tags: macos, code-signing-entitlements, findersync, macos-system-extension

My project consists of main application, an endpoint security extension and a findersync extension. When I try to build it in release mode, the findersync extension is getting built with entitlements of the main app and not one of its own. I am not seeing this issue for endpoint security. I am signing using a "Developer ID Application" signing identity.

When I look into the build logs I am seeing that `--entitlement` is used in code sign and the file which is passed as the argument also has the correct entitlement. When I tried manually running the codesign command with the `--entitlement` flag, I am still unable to get the correct entitlement.

Is there any difference in the way the codesign happens for the system extension and findersync? What changes do I need to make in order to get the correct entitlement?

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure the binary isn't already signed before you run `codesign`? It will silently avoid doing any work by default if the binary is already signed.
- Are you using an appropriate provisioning profile? Endpoint Security entitlements require a corresponding profile generated by Apple's systems.

If none of the above solves the problem, please edit your question to include more detail. The content of the entitlements file, your `codesign` command line, the output of the command you are using to verify the entitlements, etc. And: What *exactly* do you mean by

> I am still unable to get the correct entitlement.